# Unity Interception Behaviour not invoking

Tags: unity-container

In my data layer:

```
public interface IMyDataContext
{
    IMyRepository MyRepository { get ; set ; }
    // other repo's
}

public class MyDataContext : IMyDataContext
{
    public MyDataContext ( string connectionKey)
    {
        ConnectionKey = connectionKey;
        Database = new Database(ConnectionKey);
        MyRepository = new MyRepository (ConnectionKey);
        // other repo's
    }
}
```

In my Web API service layer:

Configuring unity like so in my UnityConfig class:

```
_container = new UnityContainer();
_container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

_container.RegisterType< IMyDataContext , MyDataContext >(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor >(),
    new InjectionConstructor("MyConnectionKey" )
);
```

I wish to add behaviour for auditing to the MyRepository interface, something like this,

```
_container.RegisterType< IMyRespository, MyRepository >(
    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor >(),
    new InterceptionBehavior<AuditingInterceptionBehaviour >()
);
```

only the **AuditingInterceptionBehaviour** never gets invoked if I do it this way. The only way to get it to invoke on that repo is to resolve in the constructor of my web api controller (below) but think this is not the best way to resolve it and was banking on auto resolving in the UnityConfig class.

```
public MyController( IMyDataContext datacontext)
{
    _datacontext = datacontext;
    _datacontext.MyRepository = UnityConfig.Instance.Resolve<IMyRespository>       (new ParameterOverride("connectionKey", _datacontext.ConnectionKey));
}
```

If I add the behaviour to the registering of IMyDataContext, the **AuditingInterceptionBehaviour** class DOES GET invoked but I want to get method base properties for the calling repository (in my case IMyRepository) instead of its parent (IMyDataContext).

Can this be done in my UnityConfig class or do I need something more here?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post my answer on this:

Bascially, just needed to load the service layer unity container and resolve the repo in the data layer rather than in the Web API service layer like so:

```
public class MyDataContext : IMyDataContext
{
    public MyDataContext ( string connectionKey)
    {
        ConnectionKey = connectionKey;
        Database = new Database(ConnectionKey);

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.LoadConfiguration();

        MyRepository = container.Resolve<IMyRespository>();
        // resolve other repo's
    }
}
```